# bash - command line arguments to script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

hello all newbie here :D

i am working on a project right now which involves a script that handles a *.dat file.The script runs under specific commands inputed by user

my problem is that i cant figure out how to "grab" the arguments from the command to "import" them to the script

here are some examples from the specific commands :

1. `./tool.sh -f <file>`
2. `./tool.sh -f <file> -id <id>`
3. `./tool.sh --born-since <dateA> --born-until <dateB> -f <file>`

where tool.sh is the scripts name, `<file>` is the `*.dat` file, `<date>` is just a date in this format YYYY-MM-DD

so as you can see there are both shortwords and longwords. I know that the getopts command is tricky to handle the long ones. How can i handle all of them using a "single" piece of code?

edit: i need to use the arguments and the conditional expressions for a case using the "if"

so could i just do :

```
#!/bin/bash 
getopts f a
if [ $1 == "something" && $2 == "something2" && $a == "f" ]; then
....
elif [ $1 == "something3" && $2 == "something4" && $a == "f" ]
....
else 
....
fi
```

would that be correct?

Comment: Arguments are `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

Comment: [BashFAQ #35](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

In a bash script you can access command line arguments via order like so:

```
echo $1 # the first argument
echo $2 # the second argument
```

Comment: This is buggy. If run with `./tool.sh '*'`, it would print all filenames in the current directory, not a `*`. Needs to be `echo "$1"`, with the quotes. And even then, it doesn't help the OP with parsing arguments that are named rather than positional.